# Use JavaScript regex groups to match if other groups dont match before it

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Can I use a javascript regex to capture if the first group(s) don't capture?

Here i have two(three) capturing groups:

```
/("[^\n"]*")|("[^\n"]*(?:\n|$))/g
```

What i would like is to place anything that did not match in the first two, in another like so

```
/("[^\n"]*")|("[^\n"]*(?:\n|$))|(<CATCH ANYTHING ELSE HERE>)/g
```

Is this possible?

In practice, this would mean always matching the entire string, but being able to segment it.

(I am building a code editor, trying to parse strings in the code).

I tried adding `(.*)` but that seemed to always catch "before" the other two.

EDIT:

To simplify, lets say I want to segment a string into two groups:

1. All characters that are `a`
2. All characters that are not `a`

Given the regex `/(a)|(^\1)/g`, I would assume the entire string would match but this is not the case. Why? In more complex cases I assume using [backreferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Groups_and_backreferences) is better?

Comment: Consider updating your post with 4-5 samples that get matched and same amount for not matched samples.

Comment: What is the reason for the capture groups? On a different matter, why the rush to select the first answer posted, particularly in view of the comments it has attracted? You don't want to see other answers?

Comment: Trying to create code highlighting. Just upvoted it, did not mark it:)

Comment: Depending on text size and type of patterns used, it might be more operable to use `split()` with a captured expression instead of matching and capturing all parts: `text.split(/(regex1|regex2)/)`.

Comment: I thought so for a while, but having some trouble with that solution, i decided to try capturing all parts of the string, but maybe you are right:)

Comment: Btw, i am very thankful for all the input you guys provide:)

Comment: But we are not thankful that you have disregarded @lemon's request to provide examples, which others clearly want as well. I, for one, do not understand your question. That there is but one answer suggests that other readers are in the dark as well.

Comment: `/(a)|(^\1)/` reads, "match 'a' and save to capture group 1 or match the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by the content of capture group 1 and save to capture group 2". For the second part of the alternation to be executed capture group 1 cannot contain a non-empty string. Perhaps you meant `/(a)|[^a]/`.

Answer (score 1):

This expression does the job:

```
(regex1)|(regex2)|((?:(?!regex1|regex2).)*)
```

where:

- `regex1` is your first regex
- `regex2` is your second regex
- the last group captures a single character repeated until one of the first two regexes is matched. In particular, `(?!...)` is called [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

In your example, you can use `/(a)|((?:(?!a).)*)/g`.

P.S. Note that your regex is wrong also because `^` matches the [beginning of a string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)!

P.P.S. As pointed out in comments, backreference `\1` won't work, because it refers to the actual text matched, not to the expression that catched it.

Comment: Are you sure `(?!\1|\2)` does anything? Because IIUC, third group will be checked only if first two aren't matched, and as a result backreference does nothing. Consider [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4FKvM/1). Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I agree with @markalex. Do you actually mean `(?!regex1|regex2)`? `\1` and `\2` refers to the actual *text* matched and not the expression in those groups, and are not to be confused with capturing group recursion/subroutine (`(?1)`) in PCRE/PCRE2.

Comment: Ops, you're right! I've updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: I think @markalex and InSync are asking why you didn't write `(regex1)|(regex2)|(.*)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That doesn't work because the third group won't stop matching, see for instance https://regex101.com/r/kDQk7b/1

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "third group won't stop matching". If neither `regex1` nor `regex2` match the third part of the alternation will match the entire string (or the entire first line of the string). Isn't that's what is intended?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Take the example of the OP (all characters that are `a` vs. all characters that are not `a`), and take the string `baa`. The regex `(a)|(.*)` that you suggest would match the whole string in the second group. One could indeed use `(a)|(.)` (without the asterisk), but only if the requirement is to match _single_ characters in the second group.

Comment: I see your point but the main problem is that I even less confident than before that I understand the question.